# Surface subdivision into equal parts

Tags: geometry-surface

I have a closed contour represented by a list of points and I need to split it into equal parts, knowing the area of the parts.

I think that I can use some subdivision algorithm, like Delanuy subdivision. But with this method I have to give the centroid of the subdivded parts.

Anyone has some hints?

Comment: Are you looking for a particular subdivision of the area, or ANY subdivision of the area that fulfills your criteria of part areas? Is the input contour convex? Must each resulting part be connected?

Comment: any kind is good. yes, the input is convex, and yes, the resulting part should be connected

Answer (score 2):

if i understand correctly: given say a rectangle say of area 10, and a target area of 1, you would need to partition rectangle into 10 parts, each having area of 1. So slicing the rectangles into 10 thin rectangles (like guitar frets, or bread slices) would do.

If that's the case, then I would do the following:
Create a function to compute the area of a convex poly. This is fairly trivial (since poly is convex).

Observe, since input poly is convex, any line segment that splits the polygon into two, will intersect the polygon in exactly two places. Specifically, you can triangulate the polygon by picking a vertex of the poly and connecting it to every other vert of the polygon, like a fan.

Triangulating in this fashion would create a partition that would be close to what you need.  Assume that the input polygon is given by a vertex list poly = {v1, v2, v3, ..., vn}, where verts are unique and no three are co-linear (convex poly).

Observe that given a triangle of that poly formed by say (v2,v3,v4) we can compute its area, A1. Now if we grow the triangle into a poly by adding one extra vert to the next, say v5, to form (v2, v3, v4, v5) the area increased to A2 (sum of two triangles, (v2,v3,v4) and (v2,v4,v5). Due to linearity if you wanted to grow the original triangle to say A2' where A1 < A2' < A2, you can interpolate on the line segment (v4,v5) to find v4' that will give you the right area A2' that you need.

Since you can compute the total area of initial input poly, and you know the target area of each subdivision, you can cut the input poly into pieces of desired area until you subdivide the entire thing. If you want a nicer partition, you can start from the center of the polygon, i.e. first (seed triangle) would be (center, v1,v2). Then shrink/grow it until desired area, move to the next triangle, repeat.

Hope that makes sense :D